# How can I identify files and programs connected to the kernel_task process in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, kernel

I understand that the kernel_task process is linked to several .kext files found in System/Library/Extensions (and possibly Library/Extensions ?)  How can I identify which files are contributing to the 400+ MB memory usage identified in Activity Monitor?  Is there anything I can do to uninstall or delete unneeded processes to reduce memory usage here?

Comment: The kernel_task is one process - what do you mean by "processes are contributing"

Comment: Are you talking about the kernel_task process using 400MB physical memory? It's using 2.6GB here, so 400MB doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: I guess I really mean what .kext files are related to it.  I understand that they are configuration files for various programs on Mac OS but some may be unnecessary.  How can I know which?  Can I uninstall those that are no longer needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked for some generic commands that display/manipulate kernel extensions. `kextstat` got my attention and based on its output, the 4th column is

> The number of bytes of kernel memory that the kext occupies.  If this is zero, the kext is a built-in part of the kernel that has a record as a kext for resolving dependencies among kexts.

The only problem was that its size was in hexadecimal. So I converted the hexadecimal to decimal and printed only relevant information (like kext bundle id).

```
kextstat -l -k | awk '{n = sprintf("%d", $4); print n, $6}' | sort -n
```

Breaking it down:

- `kextstat -l -k` - print a list of loaded non-built-in kexts
- `| awk '{n = sprintf("%d", $4); print n, $6}'` - pipe the output to `awk`, convert the 4th "size" column from hexadecimal to decimal, print that and the kext bundle id.
- `| sort -n` - pipe the output to `sort` command and sort the list using numerical comparison (so that "10" is not less than "1 ").

You can pipe the output to `tail -n 3` to get top 3 memory hoggers. Here are mine:

```
1757184 com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal
2572288 com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman
3923968 com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360
```

**Update:** you can also pipe this to `grep -v com.apple` to see which non-apple kexts are loaded.

Comment: Looks pretty much okay then I guess...AirPort refers to wifi in general, right?  It should be in use even if I don't have an AirPort router, right?

Comment: Yes, this one refers to WiFi in general.