# MacBook Pro 16" running hot

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro 16 inch base model. I am a programmer, which means that it is running hot when I am working. When I am working it is between 70-80 degrees celsius, but when I open activity monitor only like 10-15% of the CPU is being used. 
[image]

So my question is, how can so much of the CPU be idle but it is still run at 70-80 degrees celsius

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget you need to see the clock speed to get a better idea of energy usage.

Answer (score 2):

Idle does not mean the CPU stops. The CPU can never actually stop. At best, the CPU can go into a continuous loop, but this still requires the use of electricity. This use of electricity produces heat.

Idle means the operating system is waiting for something to do. In this case, the CPU may be use less electricity, but the electricity usage does not go to zero. I would image the temperature is more a function of the fan speed, which I assume in a correctly working Mac is high enough to protect the hardware.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having all sorts of issues with MBP 16"
Why don't you check this out, try charging with the right side :
[How to find cause of high kernel_task cpu usage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage)

Comment: Are you asking a new question or are you providing an answer?  If it’s an answer, how does it relate to the OP’s question?