# Macbook Pro 15in 2018 hook up to dual monitor lag

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, catalina, 4k

Hi I have this Macbook Pro 2018 15inch baseline model. Recently I purchased a 4k LG monitor and I plan to connect it with this MBP together with my older screen which is a Dell 2k monitor.

The setup is connect to Dell with USB-C while the LG 4k is through HDMI. On the 2k display I using default scale while the 4k I am using 2560 x 1440.

Problem now is the OS gets very lag and stuttered if I start to view some 4k videos or coding with VScode. I am really frustrated because Apple claim MBP 2018 can connect to dual 4k monitor without issues right? I hope to solve this issue, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Check if the chassis is getting too hot and you can hear the fans spinning fast. Additionally, go to the CPU tab in Activity Monitor app and check if a process named `kernel_task` is taking up high CPU percentage. The thermal management system might be causing the CPU to throttle which could explain the lag. Also, please mention the version of macOS that you are using.

Comment: My current os is Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287).
So just now i monitored with opening a 4k video from youtube using chrome browser, the kernel_task increase up to 900%.

Comment: You should see this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage