# Fans blaring again after a brief hardware fix

Tags: hardware, kernel

My 2017 MacBook Air began having a problem with a high kernel task and high CPU with fans blaring. I did a hardware test and it said there may be an issue with the SMC PFM006, there may be an issue with the power management system PPN001.

After reading online that it may be to do with the track pad's thermal sensor I took the Mac apart and disconnected then reconnected the track pad. I and also cleared the dust of the machine. I did the hardware test again and it was all clear. So I began downloading all the software that I deleted while  troubleshooting and during the downloads the problem came back.

It's giving out the same hardware errors again, however now the system seems to run a little smoother, but the fans are still blaring. Any advice?

Comment: What is a brief fix? It takes a fraction of a second for something critical to break so time doesn’t really come into the picture. Is there any detail on what hardware operation was done? What parts were removed, which steps were taken, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all fixed by buying a replacement trackpad for £20 on eBay!

Answer (score 1):

> It's giving out the same hardware errors again, however now the system seems to run a little smoother, but the fans are still blaring. Any advice?

**Change the track pad.**

Cleaning things out probably helped improve the efficiency of the cooling but it doesn't fix a faulty sensor.  If you hare still getting hardware errors, it means you have a problem with the hardware.  Software (hacks) aren't going to solve a physical issue.  It's like hearing a noise in your car and installing a louder radio and speakers to cover it up.  In the end, the problem is still there.

You're on the right track and you've done good diagnostics, you just have to take it the last mile and do the hardware fix.

Comment: so on scanning the individual sensors with TG Pro, all come up similar, 20-40 degrees, but the fan is max. does the answer still point to replacing the trackpad for you?

Comment: The *hardware* errors do.  The fan comes on because a sensor(s) is telling the SMC it's getting "hot," then the SMC spins up the fans.    TG Pro is just 3rd party software that tries to interpret what the sensors are reading, but if the sensor is faulty, how good can the info from TG Pro actually be?

Comment: it's interesting because the kernel task problem/high cpu problem has gone. could i ask you why you think this may have been solved but not the fan itself, were these separate problems?

Comment: also would it be dangerous to go on from here, manually controlling the fans

Answer (score 0):

I'd download an app like [TG Pro](https://www.tunabellysoftware.com/tgpro/) that lets you monitor the temperature of all the sensors along with the speed of the fans. This will help you isolate any problem if there is one. If all sensors register low temp and the fan is maxed out you obviously have a fan issue. The app is $10 but has a free trial.

Comment: interestingly with TG Pro, all the sensors are coming up green, within 20-40 degrees. Then at the bottom the fan itself is max 6500 rpm. where does this point me?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the [same mac that throws known issues with power management](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393877/547) - I would seek repair.

- [kernel_task high CPU and fans going crazy, no heat from mac itself](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392185/kernel-task-high-cpu-and-fans-going-crazy-no-heat-from-mac-itself)
- [Fans blaring again after a brief hardware fix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392417/fans-blaring-again-after-a-brief-hardware-fix)