# Command to identify which port the power adapter is plugged into?

Tags: macos, power, charger

Is there a command that will show which port is being used for charging? From a script, I'd like to check if the power adapter is plugged in on the left, and if so print a message suggesting charging from the right side. I have looked at `system_profiler`, `ioreg`, and `pmset` but the data related to power/charging didn't say which port. Also looking at `System Information.app`, none of the info indicates which port an adapter is plugged into.

This question is based on this answer which shows that using a left port for charging can cause slower system performance. [How to find cause of high kernel_task cpu usage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage/363933)

Comment: Good question!  +1 ... I don't have access to a Mac with USB-C ports (all are desktops or older MagSafe) so I can't test.  Can you post some of the data so I can see it?  Pastebin is fine.