# Fan running since upgrade to Big Sur and keyboard change

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

I have recently upgraded my macbook pro to Big Sur OS and also got keyboard replaced. Its not an original keyboard.
Both activities happened in about 2 days and now when i start my macbook, fan keeps running and cpu usage is high. I have uninstalled chrome, MS office apps, unchecked all folders from spotlight, logged out of icloud but nothing helped.
Fan starts running as soon as apple icon appears on startup. I even tried to start in safe mode, command line mode but fan keeps running.

Can someone please guide me on steps to resolve this.

Adding screenshots of Activity monitor:

[image: Processes sorted by CPU percentage]

[image: Processes sorted by CPU time]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of Activity Monitor showing the processes consuming most CPU?

Comment: I've found that macOS upgrades cause my MacBooks to run hotter for 2 - 3 days. I am assuming it is spotlight indexing new things, but it always goes away with a bit of time.

Comment: @nohillside I have attached screenshots of Activity monitor sorted by %age usage and cpu time.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage  Also Those look like photos of the screen. You know you can take images of the screen directly? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201361

Comment: Since you mentioned a hardware repair, one thing you should verify is that the CPU fan or vent was not unintentionally blocked in some manner causing the temperature inside to rise (one of the reason kernel_task kicks is in when CPU becomes hot). If you are sure that's not the issue, then open Console app and click on the Errors and Faults tab name. Watch if it reports any. If it does, post it here.