# CPU constantly hot with low usage

Tags: mac, temperature

My 2019 16" MacBook Pro with 2.6GHz 6-core i7 processor on macOS 11.3.1 is constantly running [hot at ~60°C even when the CPU usage is only 8-10%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHZ5p.png).
I've checked the ActivityMonitor, but no app is using excess amounts of CPU, energy, or memory.

I've obviously tried rebooting & updating my Mac. I also make sure my fans aren't blocked so there's enough room for air flow and I have cleaned the interior from dust.

What else can I do?

Comment: 60°C is not really hot. CPUs can actually exceed 100°C for short amounts of time.

Comment: Yes but it's on 60°C for the whole night even though its in standby (and afaik nothing's running)...that wasn't the case until recently.

Comment: Swap the charger to the other side. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage

Comment: Wow, I unplugged my LG UltraFine (which also charges my Mac) from the right side and the fans immediately stopped spinning. I now plugged it into the left side, and they're picking up again...so it seems related for sure. I'll see if it goes down in the next hours. @Tetsujin

Comment: There are two things at play: more pixels to push (i.e. graphic card runs hotter) and charging also creates heat.

Comment: @X_841 yes, but that has been the fact for months, and the heat problem has appeared only a few days ago – I haven't changed a thing about my setup.