# Macbook Pro 2019 overheating with external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, hdmi

**Problem**

My Macbook overheats insanely.

After investigating a bit, I found out that the correlation is extremely strong with having it plugged in to an external monitor with the Macbook Pro monitor also active.

If I unplug the laptop, or use only the external monitor (i.e. Mac in a 'clamshell' mode), the heating stops within a minute.

I managed to use a software (`sudo powermetrics --samplers smc |grep -i "CPU die temperature"`) to measure this:

- Indoor temperature: 23C
- CPU heat without external monitor: 55C
- CPU heat with external monitor + macbook monitor on: 95C (fan turns on)
- CPU heat with external monitor, macbook closed: 62C

**Details of hardware**

- Macbook Pro (16-inch, 2019). 2.3 Ghz 8-Core Intel Core i9, 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR, AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4GB, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
- macOS BigSur 11.4
- Monitor: HP E233. 23-inch (1920 x 1080)
- Cables connecting: UGREEN USB C Hub HDMI USB C Adapter with 4K HDMI, 3 USB 3.0, SD/TF Card Reader (https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07RRPS5NT/), and then a standard HDMI-cable

**Tried fixes that didn't work**

- Restart
- SMC reset
- Never use two monitors (works)

**How could I fix this so I can use two monitors also in the future?**

Comment: Is your monitor plugged in on the right or left?

Comment: Left. Dont tell me that this makes the difference :-D

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage/399321#399321 it may actually be the problem.

Comment: That trick used to fix the issue in previous versions (I had a 15" 2016 where it worked), but not anymore. I've tried both sides and now it doesn't. I have an i7 and an i9 (both late 2019) and the issue only affects the i9.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Update to latest macos Monterey
2. Go to Settings -> Battery => Check the Low power mode both for Battery and Power adapter
3. On using two 4k monitors, if possible use ports on left/right foreach monitor

Good Luck!

Comment: I tried this - it had no impact on my machine (16" i9 MPB with a single external display).

Answer (score 1):

As a MacBook Pro owner, I had the same problem. After a lot of researching, I discovered that our MacBooks have an architectural error: when plugged, an external monitor is always controlled by the dedicated GPU (the AMD Radeon, in my case).

So, as the dedicated GPU is more power-consuming and tends to heat more than the integrated one, our laptops are always overheating when connected to an external monitor.

Sources:

1. https://dnsmichi.at/2022/01/10/macbook-pro-16-2019-heat-problem-with-external-display/
2. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444119/468509

Comment: "Defiance"? I may be mistaken, but I don't think that is the correct word.

Comment: Can you please [edit] in links to the research you found?

Comment: Edited the post to correct that wrong word and to add sources. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. go to [System Preferences] -> [Displays];
2. go to [Displays Settings] if you are using both built-in monitor and external monitor, otherwise there is not [Displays Settings] and you will see the detail info of the current monitor instead.
3. remember the Color Profile of the built-in monitor. set the external monitor's Color Profile to the same as the built-in one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the culprit was a mismatch between the frame rates of external and built-in displays (50 and 60 Hz, respectively). Setting the external display to 60 Hz in **System Settings** > **Displays** solved the problem.