# Slow BOOT / Mac Mini 2018 cause: X86PlatformPlugins

Tags: startup, big-sur, kernel

After the BigSur update i've noticed a way slower boot time on my Mac Mini 2018.
Before would boot in 10-12Sek now it takes about 1'.

After booting into the verbose mode i found the Problem and where it gets stuck:
**X86PlatformPlugin fSMC_PlimitNotification** - here takes about 30'

I've researched a bit and it is a kernel extension. I tried to stop it but without luck.

HW: Mac Mini 2018, 3.2 Ghz 6-Core i7. 16 GB Ram. OS: BigSur 11.2.1

Anyone some ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I've never really investigated this on Mac, but back in the day on Windows the current process showing would be the last one fully loaded. The one halting would not be in the list yet. [Then, of course, once that was loaded the list would speed by too fast to read. that's where your iPhone's video recording comes in handy.]

Comment: Check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage