# dealing with high kernel_task cpu usage

Tags: macos, kernel

I experience high kernel_task cpu usage problems on my MacBook Pro (16-in, 2019), macOS Big Sur 11.4.

[How to find cause of high kernel_task cpu usage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage)

The solutions above don't seem to apply to my case. My battery is fully charged so it is not charging that increases the temperature of my machine. There is also no external monitor connected to my MacBook.

The high CPU usage problems seem to occur after I start some computational program that takes a lot of CPU, so that the machine becomes hot which triggers kernel_task. Even when the computational program finishes, the machine is still hot and kernel_task keeps taking a lot of CPU.

I understand that kernel_task is to let the CPU not do the actual work to prevent the machine from being too hot. But is there a way to somehow disable kernel_task? (I don't care whether my machine is hot or not.)

Comment: You cannot disable kernel_task. To over-simplify, it is essentially the 'root' of the entire operating system. Everything else on the Mac is spawned from that process. Without kernel_task you have no operating system.

Comment: How to deal with high kernel_task cpu usage?

Comment: If you've tried everything from the linked question, all that's left is to let the Mac cool down.