# kernel_task slowing down on Intel-based MacBook Pro

Tags: performance, cpu, temperature, kernel

I have a 2020 MacBook Pro 16", the last of the Intel based Macs. Just in the last couple of weeks it has been slowing down due the kernel_task process going up to 1000% CPU usage.

[image: 1300% CPU]

I have done a SMC and NVRAM reset to no avail. I have followed the advice [in this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage) and have nothing plugged in on the left side and also disabled Turbo Boost. The lid is closed with one external monitor and I have both left and right fans running at full RPM.

The usage does not seem limited to any one application (eg browser etc), it happens without or with various apps open. Temps are fine as per the image below? 60c.

[image: temps OK]

The one thing I can say is that it generally starts occurring after about 7-8 hours of work time (regardless of when I start work). Work is just browsers, nothing taxing.

Any ideas on what I can do next? Have just about had it with my laptop slowing to a crawl every single afternoon.

Comment: Your assertion that temps are fine is a bit suspect. This is classic thermal throttling - can you elaborate on how you're determining that the temperature is not the cause here with an edit?

Comment: @bmike I thought the 60c in the image meant they were OK

Comment: That temperature would be normal or low for CPU, but not if the CPU is running at 89.5 %. If you are reading the CPU temperature it should be at 90-110 C

Comment: You could unscrew the panel on the bottom of the case, and make sure there's no fluff blocking the fans and vents. Those last Intel Macs are ovens.

Comment: @Matt there are likely half a dozen temperature readings and I can’t tell what software that is and which measurement we are seeing or if it’s an average. If the battery area is that hot, you have big problems - let’s get some bottom case measurements near the heat pipes if you can’t determine exactly what was 60 C. And you can power off and then test immediately after boot. If the kernel task is game on a cold system, you know it’s heat no matter what your readings are.